# c# NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces vs WMI Win32_NetworkAdapter

Tags: wmi, ethernet

I get a InterfaceIndex with GetBestInterface (iphlpapi.dll).

The goal : read other interface properties.

This WMI query is slow :

```
SELECT MACAddress,Name,GUID,NetConnectionID FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE InterfaceIndex=
```

In C# there is, faster,

```
NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
```

but each NetworkInterface hasn't the property InterfaceIndex ( sic ! ).

I don't know how to optimize this :

```
    EnumerationOptions wmi_options = new EnumerationOptions();
    wmi_options.Rewindable = false;
    wmi_options.ReturnImmediately = true;
    string wql = "SELECT MACAddress,Name,GUID,NetConnectionID FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE InterfaceIndex=" + iface;
    ManagementObjectCollection recordset = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\cimv2", wql, wmi_options).Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in recordset)
```

The options don't seem to help.
Can I split the operations and cache any step ?

Or another path : avoid WMI and lookup the interface ( with InterfaceIndex ) from the registry ?

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces
>
> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}

Comment: I find and upvote the [solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11059702/471232

Comment: So my last question is, in general : how to cache and speed-up wmi queries ?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this is actually faster but have you tried powershell?

```
string IfIndex = "15";
        string psscript = "get-netadapter |  Where-Object interfaceindex -eq " + IfIndex;
        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        powershell.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        powershell.Runspace.Open();
        powershell.AddScript(psscript);
        foreach (PSObject result in powershell.Invoke())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} " + "Status: {1}",result.Members["Name"].Value, result.Members["status"].Value);
        }
        Console.Read();
```

run this from your application, using  System.Management.Automation &
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

i haven't tested the code yet, this is the top of my head.